# Function value not getting displayed in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I've created a class in Typescript.
When I am trying to convert this into js and run using command prompt, I am not getting desired output.
Here is my class

```
class myclass{
    
    j: number;

    constructor(k: number){
        this.j = k;

    }
    value (){
        return("the number is "+this.j)
    }

}

let myobj = new myclass(10)
    console.log(myobj.value) .
```

Can u suggest what's not working in this.?

Comment: `myobj.value()`  parenthesis missing ?

Comment: this is typio.  u missed parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

`myobj.value` is a function.

To print the actual value you have to call the function using `myobj.value()`

---

You can spot your mistake using the `typeof` keyword, that tells you the type of a variable.

```js
class myclass {
  j;

  constructor(k) {
    this.j = k;
  }
  
  value() {
    return `the number is ${this.j}`;
  }
}

const myobj = new myclass(10);

console.log(typeof myobj.value);
```